# If-statement gets ignored?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I'm kind of stuck with strange behaviour of my code and I really hope, someone could help me..

**Objective**
I'm trying to build a (multiple) magnetic stirring device with which I can either control the speed via potentiometer or via serial commands from a python script from pc (usb).
When the speed is set via serial, it shouldn't be possible to interfere with the potentiometer unless a button is pressed to unlock it.

**Code**

```
// Constants

const int FanPin[7] = {2,3,5,6,7,8,9}; // PWM Pins 2,3,5,6,7,8,9 for fan
const int PotiPin[7] = {A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6}; // Analoge Pins 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 for potentiometers
const int SwitchPin[7] = {30,31,32,33,34,35,36}; // Digital Pins 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36 for switches

// Variables
boolean ManualLock = false; // will be true if locked by serial input
int Fan[7][2] = { // [x][] for number of fan, [][0] for fan speed, [][1] for ManualLock
  {0, ManualLock},
  {1, ManualLock},
  {2, ManualLock},
  {3, ManualLock},
  {4, ManualLock},
  {5, ManualLock},
  {6, ManualLock}
};
int temp = 0; // Variable for temporary data
int FanSpeed[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // Variable fan speed
int PotiVar[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ; // Variable for saving poti-input
byte bfr[2] = {7,7}; // Buffer for serial data

void setup() {

TCCR2B = TCCR2B & 0b11111000 | 0x01; // Timer2 (Pin 9, 10) @ 31000Hz
TCCR3B = TCCR3B & 0b11111000 | 0x01; // Timer3 (Pin 2, 3 und 5) @ 31000Hz
TCCR4B = TCCR4B & 0b11111000 | 0x01; // Timer4 (Pin 6, 7 und 8) @ 31000Hz

Serial.begin(9600);
delay(100);

// Declaration of Pin Modes
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  pinMode(FanPin[i], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PotiPin[i], INPUT);
  pinMode(SwitchPin[i], INPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  // ManualLock not active -> manual mode
  if (!Fan[i][1]){
    //Serial.print(i);
    //Serial.println(" ManualLock not active");
    PotiVar[i] = analogRead(PotiPin[i]);
    Fan[i][0] = map(PotiVar[i], 51, 1023, 60, 255);
    //Serial.println(Fan[i][0]);
  }
  //ManualLock active -> unlock by pressing button
  if (Fan[i][1]){ 
    temp = digitalRead(SwitchPin[i]);
    if (temp == HIGH){
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(" ManualLock will be deactivated");
      Fan[i][1] = false;
      Serial.print("Fan[i][1]: ");
      Serial.println(Fan[i][1]);
    }
  }

  // fan off @ low poti setting
  if (PotiVar[i] < 50){
    Fan[i][0] = 0;
  }
}

// look for serial data

if (Serial.available()){
  Serial.println("Something's there!");
  Serial.readBytes(bfr, 2);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Serial data: ");
  Serial.println(bfr[0]);
//  Serial.flush();
}

//Serial.print("before loop bfr[0]: ");
//Serial.println(bfr[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  if (i == int(bfr[0])){
    Serial.print("i: ");
    Serial.println(i);
    Fan[i][0] = int(bfr[1]); //set fan speed variable
    Fan[i][1] = true; // activate ManualLock variable
    byte bfr[2] = {7,7}; // clear buffer
    Serial.print("bfr[0]: ");
    Serial.println(int(bfr[0]));
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  analogWrite(FanPin[i], Fan[i][0]); // write fan speed
  }
}
```

**Error(s)**

When I send a command via my python script, the speed is set correctly and I get the following output:

```
Something's there!
Serial data: 0
i: 0
bfr[0]: 7
i: 0
bfr[0]: 7
...and again and again and again...
```

Which means, although i "reset" my buffer variable to something that should prevent entering the if-statement, it will somehow fulfill the "if (i == int(bfr[0]))" condition.. but why?
If any further information is needed, i'll happily provide that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (inside your `for` loop) does not do what I think you think it does:

```
byte bfr[2] = {7,7}; // clear buffer
```

You think it sets the contents of the `bfr` array you declared at the top to `{7,7}` but what it actually does is declare a new byte array in that scope, containing the values `{7,7}`. It's not used and is immediately thrown away again.

I would expect the compiler to warn about it -- does it?  (If so, take it as a lesson not to ignore compiler warnings!)

I think you want to replace it with

```
bfr[0] = 7;
bfr[1] = 7;
```

or something equivalent.

Comment: unfortunately, there was no warning.
but now it works! thank you so much!